# How to specify "not null" to Spring Data REST / QueryDsl for a HTTP query parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I have Spring Data REST application that uses QueryDsl. My application has a `Car` entity with a `purchaseDate` field:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private LocalDate purchaseDate;
}
```

The `CarRespository` is exposed via Spring Data REST at `localhost/api/cars`:

```
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long>, 
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Car>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QCar> {
}
```

An HTTP client can find cars purchased on a date by making a GET request to:

```
localhost/api/cars?purchaseDate=2023-01-01
```

Is it possible for a HTTP client to request all cars that have a purchase date (i.e., `purchaseDate` is not null)? I know that I can add a repository method such as `findByPurchaseDateNotNull` to accomplish this but was wondering if either

1. the HTTP client can some way specify "not null" or
2. QueryDsl binding could be configured to handle a not null indication from the client

Comment: If the value is supposed to be never null you can make it required at the endpoint configuration. So it need to be there. Otherwise you can also add `@Valid @NotNull` using validation framework OR wrap it from raw type into own wrapper that requires a value and is not nullable. I prefer the last way since it is globally, typesafe and highly reuseable/scaleable.